# Which contract is satisfied

Tags: java, oop, interface

Suppose I have 2 interfaces, interface `IOne` -

```
interface IOne{
   public method();
}
```

and interface `ITwo` -

```
interface ITwo{
   public method();
}
```

All we know interface is a contract for implementing class which have to be met by the implementing class. Now If a class `X` implements both of the `interface` - `IOne` and `ITwo` which interface method is actually implemented? Or in other word which contract is fulfilled?

Thanks in advance.